# Dataframe recursively calculate values with conditions [complicated logic]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion

It seems like I cannot solve this on my own even though I already tried hard so I would like to seek your support in this matter. Thanks and appreciated in advance for your help.

Input Pandas dataframe:

```
day   a     
1     1000  
2     0     
3     0     
4     -1200 
5     0     
6     0     
7     -50   
8     0     
9     0     
10    0     
11    -150
```

Output:

```
day   a     b    c   d
1     1000  1000 100 100
2     0     1000 100 200
3     0     1000 100 300
4     -1200 100  10  10
5     0     100  10  20
6     0     100  10  30
7     -50   50   5   35
8     0     50   5   40
9     0     50   5   45
10    0     50   5   50
11    -100  -50  0   0
```

Explain:

- a is daily amount.
- b is accumulated sum of a, but with a condition, explained below.
- c = b * 10%
- d = accumulated sum of c

The problem here is the logic for column B. At the day when there is a minus amount in column a:

- if a + b(of previous day) + d(of previous day) is > 0, then b = the result, d = c (previous d already been added to b, so remove previous d);
  e.g. line day = 4
- if a + b(of previous day) > 0, then b = previous b + a; d = previous d + c ; e.g. line day = 7
- if a + b(of previous day) + d(of previous day) <= 0, then c, d turn to 0; e.g. line day = 11

I have been stuck for days so your help is really appreciated! If there is any questions please let me know.

Comment: The phrase `b is kind of accumulated sum of a. c is 10% of b on daily basis. and d is accumulated sum of c.` does not tells anything. The only thing it tells is that `b = b(a)`, `c=c(b)`, `d=d(c)`. It is not a reasonable thing to expect other people to know the task as you do. If you would like some help, please consider making all the relations explicit, at least in words if not equations. Also, stack overflow tries to stick to a scientific style as it save people time to read through it. For future, try to just asking for help, no need to describe the struggles.

Comment: Hi Aramakus, I did elaborate: the logic for column b in the following part, starting from "The problem here is the logic for column B. At the day when there is a minus amount in column a: etc." I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is way too complex to be achieved with vectorized methods. So IMHO, the best way is to forget Pandas and simply process arrays. As in the end we use the results to feed the dataframe, I would use numpy arrays instead of plain lists. Code could be:

```
# prepare the numpy arrays for the existing column and the new ones
A = df['a'].to_numpy()
B = np.ndarray(A.shape)
C = np.ndarray(A.shape)
D = np.ndarray(A.shape)

# initialize initial values of b, c and d to 0
b = c = d = 0

# loop over A and compute b, c, and d according to the requirements
for i, a in enumerate(A):
    if a + b > 0:
        b += a
        c = b // 10
        d += c
    elif a + b + d > 0:
        b += a + d
        c = b // 10
        d = c
    else:
        b += a
        c = d = 0
    # feed the arrays
    B[i], C[i], D[i] = b, c, d

# add the new columns to the DataFrame
df['B'] = B
df['C'] = C
df['D'] = D
```

It gives as expected:

```
    day     a       B      C      D
0     1  1000  1000.0  100.0  100.0
1     2     0  1000.0  100.0  200.0
2     3     0  1000.0  100.0  300.0
3     4 -1200   100.0   10.0   10.0
4     5     0   100.0   10.0   20.0
5     6     0   100.0   10.0   30.0
6     7   -50    50.0    5.0   35.0
7     8     0    50.0    5.0   40.0
8     9     0    50.0    5.0   45.0
9    10     0    50.0    5.0   50.0
10   11  -100   -50.0    0.0    0.0
```

Comment: @jezrael: Certainly. I'm not used to numba nor Cython. I use plain C when performance is critical ;-)

Comment: I think here is very easy convert your solution to numba, check some solution from @jpp how do it.

Comment: Thanks @SergeBallesta for your solution, it looks great. But for the sake of simplicity, I have narrowed the dataset down to minimum. This is only for 1 account and just 11 days, while in actual, there are like 1 million of accounts and the date went back to 2011 till now...